# How to filter in DynamicFrame before unnested in AWS Glue?

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

All,

I need to filter a DynamicFrame before the unnested, because this base is huge, but I'm not getting it.  I tried using a lambda function to filter but it's taking too long.  How else could I filter?

```
cdy = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
    database="ga",
  table_name="ga_events"
).select_fields(paths=["hits", "customDimensions"])

cdy_filter = Filter.apply(
    frame=cdy,
   f = lambda x: x["hits.eventInfo.eventCategory"] == "View"

cdy_un = cdy_filter.unnest()
```

I tried to do it with explode in spark, but it is taking too long.